# Binding Linq-to-SQL Query results to Stringbuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use a LINQ-to-SQL query to generate a hard copy report using a `StringBuilder`. My LINQ query stores its data in a variable called `Entrants`, and generates a list of data by design.

I know this is really low level, but how do I setup the `foreach` loop to make my `StringBuilder` iterate through each set of data in var `Entrants`?

```
foreach ([what goes here?] in Entrants)
{
    do something
}
```

Comment: You could always look at saving the repeater body HTML as a webpage and open the webpage in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Shoot. I hoped I got the edit in before anyone responded. Sorry, Cameron, but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: That's not a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placeholder in your code should be used to specify a name for a single entrant:

```
foreach (var entrant in Entrants)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entrant);
}
```

Without that name you couldn't reference the entrant in the loop body. You couldn't print it.

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can make your foreach variable whatever you want as in this example. If you wanted to use `StringBuilder`, just replace the `Console.WriteLine` statement with your string builder operation.

Comment: You did, usr. I *think* I'm good to go now; going to test it first. I will click the checkmark if that solves my problem.